# How to resolve module build failed due to failure in finding '@bulma/css/bulma.css' in angular?

Tags: angular, bulma

I am trying to use bulma css for my angular project. After i installed bulma with 
`npm i --save bulma`I tried including bulma in my styles.css file with

```
@import "@bulma/css/bulma.css";
```

I am getting an error stating the 'bulma.css' file cannot be found.
[image]

How can I resolve it? By the way I checked "nodex_modules" folder to see if the bulma was properly installed or not and It is present there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax: `~bulma/css/bulma`, if that doesn't work, try with switching to `.scss` files instead of `.css`